# Reusable mapping method in Entity Framework that retrieves selected columns

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping

I have 2 following queries in Entity Framework here:

Example 1:

```
var c1 = context.CardholderEntities.Where(c => c.IsActive).Select(Mapper.Map).ToList();
```

Example 2:

```
var c2 = context.CardholderEntities.Where(cc => cc.IsActive).Select(cc => new Cardholder
{
    Id = cc.Id,
    CardholderNo = cc.CardholderNo
}).ToList();
```

Here's how my mapper looks like

```
    internal static Cardholder Map(CardholderEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return null;
        return new Cardholder
         {
             Id = entity.Id,
             CardholderNo = entity.CardholderNo
         };
    }
```

Now, when I run these 2 statements in SQL profiler, in the first one, I'll get this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[CardholderNo] AS [CardholderNo], 
[Extent1].[IsVisitor] AS [IsVisitor], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[NRIC] AS [NRIC], 
[Extent1].[DepartmentId] AS [DepartmentId], 
[Extent1].[Photo] AS [Photo], 
[Extent1].[Handphone] AS [Handphone], 
[Extent1].[Remark] AS [Remark], 
[Extent1].[IsAMRMode] AS [IsAMRMode], 
[Extent1].[IssueNo] AS [IssueNo], 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[SurName] AS [SurName]   
FROM [dbo].[Cardholder] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[IsActive] = 1
```

In the 2nd one, I'll get

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[CardholderNo] AS [CardholderNo]
FROM [dbo].[Cardholder] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[IsActive] = 1
```

Now, what I want is just for the query to just retrieve 2 columns.

My questions are:

1) Why does entityframework behaves this way?

2) How can I refactor my mapper such that it can remain as a reusable method vs having to manually map them like in the 2nd example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Exmaple 2 to make sql queries Entity Framework use System.Linq.Expressions.Expression. Passing expression to Select is like passing 'definition of function' and EF makes poper sql query from Expression

When you pass a function like in Example 1, EF know only that your function need entity thats why EF makes query for all properties of entity.

You have to pass Expression to Select, you need to change your function to:

```
internal static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<CardholderEntity, Cardholder>> Map  = m => new Cardholder { CardholderNo = m.CardholderNo, Id = m.Id };
```

It is not so simple, but I hope I explain a little. You should make your own function that get `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<>>>` as parametr and see what expression and func really are;)